# Proyecto unificado de php

Tags: php

Tengo un proyecto `php` con varias versiones, pero en cada versión hay modificaciones, ya que esto no se previo desde el principio ¿Qué recomendaciones me darían para unificar y sacar un solo proyecto de esto?

Comment: Me imagino que hay archivos que se quedaron en las carpetas que ya dejaron de usarse, y archivos con versiones mas nuevas, si es asi, has un recorrido por el sistema y ve copiando lo que ocupas en otra carpeta, la cual contendra solo lo necesario.

Comment: y empieza a utilizar git (busca algun servicio que te interese, tipo gitlab, bitbucket, github...) para ir actualizando, y cada vez que tengas una "version" puedas marcarla con un tag de version.